# Macbook Pro mouse hangs, touchbar hangs, keyboard hangs

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-pro

Macbook Pro (2017) cursor moves properly, but hover and click is completely unable to work (I couldn't click the Apple Menu).

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't work either, and besides, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> doesn't even work (normally touchbar would respond on <kbd>Fn</kbd>).

(Keyboard lighting works, screen auto-dimming works.)

Any tips on how I can at least get the ≪Force Quit≫ window to open?

(Btw, 
I've got much work going on and force restart will be deadly. Do you think Apple store engineers are able to solve the hang if I brought it to the store?)

Comment: Apple store is going to reboot to their network OS, so it will be the same as just powering off and on, which is what i would do

Comment: Please try to create a new user account (administrator) and report back how your machine behaves.

Comment: @oa-, ? I'm already using the default admin. Besides, I'm trying to avoid having to force restart here... that's the whole point.

Comment: @cmason, Do you mean that even bringing to the store, there would be no way to save all the running programs unsaved data and state?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, please add a _new_ admin account and try to login with it. Then we can see if it's an issue with your user account (software) or your MacBook (hardware).

Comment: Have you tried a USB keyboard?  Any standard USB keyboard will be fine.

Comment: @Allan, At that moment I didn't thought of that, but it doesn't work for a separate issue https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/306820/6533 , so I doubt it will work here too.