# MacBook Pro keyboard dead, mouse can't click above taskbar

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, trackpad

I was using Safari and I moved the cursor to the top right-hand corner. It shows the "switch screen" fine:

[image]

(sample cropped image; whiteboxes-censor)

At that moment, the keyboard is dead. **The mouse/trackpad is able to move fine, yet can't click above the task bar.** When I click items in the menu bar, it is able to respond (icon color changes) but nothing happens.

When I right-click items in the menubar, it shows the right-click menu, but I can't do anything with that menu since it's above the taskbar. I tried a USB keyboard—doesn't work too.

Any ideas? (<kbd>[Details](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/306820/20)</kbd>)

(MacOS Sierra 10.12.5; Macbookpro 15inch 2017 1TB 2.9GHz)

---

**Edit**

I've already forced a restart. Thus separately, anyone knows what logs I can look into to see what has been causing this problem?

Comment: Pacerier can I ask why it is you keep editing (and rolling back) this question? Is there something you're trying to do but are having problems with? Can I help?

Comment: @Monomeeth, Hi, I'm editing the question and trying to link the "details" in a separate portion. But it would collapse (delete) all edits within 5 minutes except for rollbacks. So that's the only way.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just include the details within the question? Perhaps at the end, under a subheading like *More details* or something similar? From what I can gather, the details aren't too long for you to do this.

Comment: @Monomeeth, The overload might detract the reader from the message.

Comment: Ok. If you're worried you're going to end up having too much text in the details, you can use a service such as https://pastebin.com to upload the text to and then just link to that. However, the amount of detail you have at the moment isn't too much. If you still have problems linking to the extra detail, I would just add it to the question. Otherwise, if all is good now, just leave it as is. BTW, it's an interesting question you have. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth, Ok I'll use pastebin in future for plaintext.